# Passing array of selected values from select2 multiple to Flask

Tags: jquery, flask

**html:**

```
<form method="POST">
    <span id="searchProject" style="width: 50%"></span>
    <span id="searchHR" style="width: 50%"></span>
</form>
```

**jquery:**

```
function loader() {
    var selectedValues = [];
    $("#searchHR:selected").each(function(){
        selectedValues.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(selectedValues);

    $.getJSON('/query_values', {
        selected_HR: selectedValues,
        selected_project: $('#searchProject').val(),
    })
}
```

**flask:**

```
@app.route('/query_values', methods=['POST'])
def query_values():
    project = request.args.get('selected_project', type=str)
    hr = request.args.get('selected_HR')
    print(hr)
    return project, hr
```

`console.log(selectedValues):` [A0, A10]

> GET /query_values?selected_HR%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=0&selected_HR%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=A0&selected_HR%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=1selected_HR%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=A10&selected_project=Catch123 HTTP/1.1

`print(hr):` None

Why is the value of `hr` returning None? I have tried to serialize `(selectedValues)` and it returns undefined undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to add JSON.stringify to selectedValues.

```
$.getJSON('/query_values', {
    selected_HR: JSON.stringify(selectedValues),
    selected_project: $('#searchProject').val(),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode array parameters with traditional style.

```
$.getJSON({
    url:'/query_values', 
    data:{
        selected_HR: selectedValues,
        selected_project: $('#searchProject').val(),
    },
    traditional:true // important !!
});
```

Get array params with `getlist` method

```
@app.route('/query_values', methods=['POST'])
def query_values():
    project = request.args.get('selected_project', type=str)
    hr = request.args.getlist('selected_HR')
    print(hr)
    return project, hr
```